# Add simple 5 star rating system in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and want to add 5 star rating system . Now the issue is that there are many free plugins for that but they add rating system to pages, posts and comments. My case is a little different where i am developing a customised solution and I want to add rating row in all the rows in my for loop and link my voting with a table on the backend. I am just pasting the code of a form which display multiple rows and I want to add rating system at the end of this code. Please guide what is the best solution to do that. I know the concept of jquery hover and use stars as divs background and use star as the submit buttons. But how to implement this can anybody guide in this. Thanks

php code (Rating to be added for each row of this loop)

```
<?
foreach( $results as $result ) {
$form.= '<form id="voteform" action="" method="post">';
$form.= "<input name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>"; 
$form.= "<input name='aid' type='hidden' value='$result->aid'>";
$form.= "Title :".$result->title.'<br>';
$form.= "<div class='mg-image' style='margin-top:15px;'><img id='articlecontest' src='$result->path' width='250' height='250' ></div>" . '<br><br>';


$form.= "<input name='competition' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
$form.= "Username :".$result->username.'<br>';

$form.= "Total Votes:".$result->votessum.'<br>';
$form.= "<div id='articlesummary'>".$result->articlebody."</div>";

$form.="<div id='clickme' style='color:blue; font-size:16px; font-family: Satisfy, Cursive;'>".'READ MORE'."</div>";
$form.= do_shortcode('[xrr rating=4/5]');
$form.= '<div id="articlebody">'.'This is body text'.$result->body.'</div>';
$form.= "<input  class='vote' value='two' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'/>";

$form .= "<input  class='vote' value='one' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'/><form>"; ?>
```

The main question is how to add rating to php code ... adding to pages or posts might be easy with free plugins

Comment: Your question is ? to know how to add a 5-star-rating system in this code ? or the logic for it ?

Comment: I want to know the logic because if I use stars and consider them as multiple submit buttons for the form tag and each star may have hover and click events but how to have each star add vote to database through ajax in wordpress and after adding vote I want the page to be refreshed and show total votes. All this with ajax I want. And this is wordpress please consider this also thanks

Comment: you can send an ajax request once the user has clicked on any of the stars. On the other end you can identify the user's input based on the `ID` of the button which you should send along with the AJAX request. Thus, 1-star will have ID=id1 and so on.. and in the response of the AJAX you can simply change the div to show the total/average rating

Comment: Abhishek this is wordpress so just above the ajax call I can assign the value to a variable based on the star which is clicked but kindly note that vased on the clicked star we need to perform database vote insert operation and also display sum of votes for that item all with ajax. So how can this different operations be possible with ajax on clicking any star. Can anybody give an idea ... thanks